# Installing z3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mono, c#

I installed Z3 on the mono in Ubuntu 18.04 according to the steps mentioned at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 and got the message of success, but Z3 does not work properly and it is not in the Microsoft.z3.dll file in Mono or GAC.

```
For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks/.NETFramework/v4.5.2/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "/usr/lib/mono/4.5.2-api/Facades/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{GAC}".
          Considered "Microsoft.Z3", which was not found in the GAC.
          For SearchPath "{RawFileName}".
          Considered treating "Microsoft.Z3" as a file name, but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "bin/x64/Release/".
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "bin/x64/Release/Microsoft.Z3.exe", but it didn't exist.
```

```
"/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  PolicySynthesis.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
  Synthesize.cs(17,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Z3' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/mahdieh/Spire-master/Spire/Spire.csproj]
```

Comment: Have you tried asking the developer?  I think that should be the first place to ask since the odds of finding someone on AskUbuntu that has the same problem isn't 0, but it should be fairly low.  For me, seeing error messages about ".exe" and having a question with the tag about C# makes me wonder why it would work on an Ubuntu system.  But I know nothing about what you're doing...  Good luck!

Comment: Hi, you're right, this is a C # program written to implement an article and run on Ubuntu. I have asked the authors many times, but the original author, who is the programmer of this program, has not answered, and I had to ask my questions here and in the stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ray Like many Mono and .NET Core programs and libraries, this is cross-platform. C# is not Windows-specific. Mono and .NET Core programs use .exe and .dll files on non-Windows systems. See [Is knowledge of C# of any use in a Linux system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1022007) and [What are .dlls doing in Linux programs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/954173) Also, I don't think the odds of finding someone here who can answer this are all that low. z3 is rather popular. (I used it in Ubuntu yesterday, though I used the Python library, `z3-solver` in PyPI.) I expect some folks here use it from C#.

Comment: @mahdiehhejazi My personal opinion is if the developer is not replying to you, you should consider another option.  Of course, I do hope someone here can help you, but an unsupported program that cannot even be installed properly is difficult to work with...  (On the other hand, an unsupported program that 'works' is perfectly fine.  Might be perfectly stable.  I've seen that too!  Good luck!)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for letting me know!  Though I guess I didn't mean that z3 isn't popular.  What I meant is that I guess z3 for C# might be less popular than for (say) Python.  Perhaps the OP should consider StackOverflow if there are no replies here?  At least you open your audience to non-Ubuntu users as well.